# iOS Rest Webservice Returning Invalid Host Error

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

We have an application which requires a rest webservice to be called (for the login screen). While calling this webservice, we are able to receive the result occasionally, but many times, we're getting null data with the following message:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Invalid Host Specified</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>The request did not specify a valid virtual host.</BODY></HTML>
```

After we get this error, we are not able to receive any other result and the app gets stuck in the login screen. We have to close the app and open it and try again to see if the webservice works.

What could be reason behind this error? We tried both `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` to receive the result but both are having the same issue. It would be really helpful if someone gives a solution for this or at least point me in the right direction in solving the issue.

This is the function which I'm using to call the web service:

```
-(void)startWebServiceForURL:(NSString *)URL withInputJson:(NSString *)inputJson forView:(UIView *)parentView completionBlock:(DownloadCompletionBlock)completionBlock errorHandlingBlock:(DownloadErrorBlock)ErrorBlock
{

    if (_showIndicator)
    {

        UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
        UIViewController *viewC = [window rootViewController];
        _progressIndicator = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:viewC.view animated:YES];

    }


    _completion = completionBlock;
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setValue:@"application/json"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[inputJson length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[inputJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0f];

    NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
                           if (_showIndicator)
                           {
                               [_progressIndicator hideAnimated:YES];
                           }


                           if (!error && data != nil)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"result received!!!");

                               NSError * error1;

                               {
                                   NSLog(@"print something else");

                                   NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                   NSLog(@"new string: %@", newStr);

                                   NSDictionary * jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error1];

                                   NSLog(@"received data: %@", jsonDictionary);

                                   if (!error1)
                                       _completion(YES,jsonDictionary);
                                   else
                                   {
                                       _error = ErrorBlock;
                                       _error(error1);
                                   }
                               }

                           }
                           else
                           {
                               NSLog(@"error receiving result");
                               _error = ErrorBlock;
                               _error(error);

                               if ( error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"not connected");
                               }
                           }
                       });


    }] resume];
}
```

Comment: You probably need to post some code so people can see what you are attempting to do. I doubt that your description alone will give anyone enough to go on

Comment: What makes you sure, this error is related to NSURLConnection or NSURLSession? Hint: How about the web service?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper - Just checked NSURLConnection because I frequently used it before iOS 8.

Comment: What I'm trying to hint at is, that you should check the possibility for an improperly configured web service.

Comment: NO @CouchDeveloper same webservice is working very fine in android applications

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, all of the following are true:

- You're contacting an Oracle web server.
- Multiple domain names point to that server's IP address.
- One of them isn't listed in the web server's config file.
- That's the domain that your app is trying to access.

The only other possibilities I can think of are that either you're trying to access the host by its IP address or you're making HTTP/1.0 requests (which lack a Host header).